# How to prove $W$ is a vector subspace of $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need some help to solve this problem.

Let $V \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}:$

$W := \{A \in V : A = -A^T\}.$

How can I prove that $W$ is vector subspace of $V$?

Comment: Do you know what a subspace and how to check that? If yes, then where are struggling? If not, then look it up.

Comment: Is it closed under scalar multiplication and addition in $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$?

Comment: Use the "solution verification" tag if and only if you present an attempted solution to verify.

Answer (score 0):

I think , that it should read $V = \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}.$

You have to show that for $ \alpha \in \mathbb R, A \in W$ and $B \in W$ it holds that

1. $ \alpha A \in W$

and

2. $A+B \in W.$
3. Confirm the zero vector exists in $W$.

You need the rules $ ( \alpha A)^T= \alpha A^T$ and $(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T.$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I did the following can you please check: the zero matrix is in W, (alpha*A_1 + beta*A_2) = alpha*A_1 + beta*A_2 = alpha*(-A_1^T) + beta*(-A_2^T). Does this complete the proof?